# CMake: how to install only shared libraries found via find_library?

Tags: cmake, installation, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I've got several third-party libs, some them shared, some static, I need to install the shared ones.

Currently I'm doing find_library's, have a list of all the needed libs and pass it to `install(FILES ...)`.

But this way both `.a` and `.so` libs are installed.

With `install(TARGETS ...)` there is a separation on `RUNTIME`, `ARCHIVE` etc.
But I do not want to create a dummy target for each of the libs.

I also do not want to separate libs into shared and static (there is another separation already).

Is there a nicer way for me to filter for shared libs only than just to regex the filename? Maybe libraries are treated as something 'more' than just filepaths after `find_library` so I somehow can get library type from them?

Comment: `Maybe libraries are treated as something 'more' than just filepaths after find_library so I somehow can get library type from them?` - No, `find_library` just returns a path. It doesn't know whether a library is static or shared. What is wrong in checking a library's type with regex? You may use variable [CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html) for make the check to be cross-platform.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I dunno :D it just seems clunky in general, but I guess it's just what CMake is :)

Comment: I think there is a misconception. find_library is to get the path so you can link against that library. It is not meant to include external libraries for packaging or installation.

Comment: @usr1234567 well, then how do I do that? :) I need both to find a downloaded library and install it

Comment: Use another tool. Probably Docker, a virtual machine or similar approaches might help you. CMake seems to be not the right match for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what is going on.

1. You install some libraries via you package manager (yum/dnf/apt-get/sth else).
2. You build your app.
3. You distribute your app.

If so, you should not ask cmake to install those libs, because if someone else would like to install same thirdparty libs via another rpm package, it would create conflict (and one package would have to be removed) - it's mess.

The place which manage library dependecies is package manager - create rpm package which would have:

```
Requires: all_your_dynamic_libs
BuildRequires: all_your_static_libs
```

If point 1 is rather - You install some libraries by make && make install then you should firstly create rpm package for that.

It is kind of a pain to create all this additional work, but trust me, you DO NOT want to create all-in-one package.

Comment: we are providing a custom hardware, a custom OS build, on which we are installing lots of our custom software (which requires some dynamic libs to work), and all that is designed to work (after installation of our RPMs) as is, without any interrogation from the customer. I mean, customer is not guaranteed to have access to repositories, let alone internet. Where are they supposed to download libs from? I'm downloading libraries to the CI server from the local Artifactory server via CMake's ExternalProject.

Comment: and by the way even there was an ability for the customer 
to download libs themselves from some third party, there could be a possibility of access absence or not perfect version matching (well, I guess we can enforce it for this one) and some of the our software could break because of that; there should be a solution where customers do not depend on any third parties, let alone the internet

Comment: Why don't you deploy those libs the same way as you do with OS/applications?

I bet you are preparing OS image and then then deploying it to hardware? So you should create this image along with your apps and with those thirdparty libs.

What is more you could check Yocto project - it seems exactly like sth that you are looking for.

I would ask another question here on stackoverflow - about delivering whole OS onto hardware. I am not an expert in deploying soft to embedded. And it goes out of scope of your original question.